# According to Newton’s law of cooling, the temperature u(t ) of an object satisﬁes the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

According to Newton’s law of cooling, the temperature u(t) of an object satisﬁes the differential equation

du/dt= −k(u−T)

where T is the constant ambient temperature and k is a positive constant. Suppose thatthe initial temperature of the object is u(0)= u0.

(a) Find the temperature of the object at any time. (I know how to resolve this)

b) Let τ be the time at which the initial temperature difference u0 − T has been reduced by half. Find the relation between k and τ. (I don't understand why the result is "ln 2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the differential equation is given by
$$\Delta T(t)=\Delta T(0)e^{-kt}$$
where $\Delta T(t)=u(t)-T$, $\Delta T(0)=u_0-T.$
You have that
$$\Delta T(\tau)=\frac{\Delta T(0)}{2}=\Delta T(0)e^{-k\tau}\iff \frac{1}{2}=e^{-k\tau}$$
Take natural logarithm from both sides to obtain:
$$\ln(2^{-1})=-k\tau\iff k\tau =\ln 2$$